# How to get a call back when DOM is ready after external ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension to keep track of the profiles I visit on LinkedIn.In the new LinkedIn UI most of the calls happen over ajax and a complete page-reload is not happening. Is there any way for my chrome extension to get a call back when the future element is available? I have tried delegate method of jquery it doesn't work for change or load event.

Comment: [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: The problem with the above method is that the call back is fired for every addition. Say there are 10 li elements then for every addition of li element i am getting a callback. How will I know when the complete insertion has been done.

Comment: It's site-specific. The link shows that some sites use a pjax:end event that signals the end of all async updates so try finding an event for your site or something else.

Comment: For example, LinkedIn uses Ember framework, so you can try inspecting `Ember` object in the [DOM context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) and try finding a way to subscribe to the route/event completion.

Answer (score 1):

The `delegate()` method of jQuery is deprecated. You can use either [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) method of jQuery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266872/document-ajaxcomplete-doesnt-fire-inside-of-content-script Have you tried using it? doesn't work for me in my content script but works in my console.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: When i paste
`$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    console.log("works only in clonsole");
});`
It works in console but when i put the same code in content script of my extension, it doesn't work..Other jquery works

Comment: because you are on a different context. see content script vs. injecting script in other s.o. answers.